# 他のサーバへプログラムの実行指示を出すには？

Tags: python, network

コンピュータAとコンピュータBがあり、Bにはprogram.pyがあって、Bのコマンドプロンプトで「python program.py」とするとprogram.pyが実行されます。

このprogram.pyをコンピュータAからの指示で実行するにはどういう方法がありますか？

追記
動作環境は、コンピュータAがWindows 10、BはLinux（Ubuntu）です。コンピュータAでアプリケーションを作って、「B上でpython.pyを実行するボタン」をクリックするとB上で「python python.py」が実行されるようにしたいです。

Comment: 該当コンピュータA/Bの動作環境（OS, ネットワーク環境など）に想定や制約があれば、質問文中に明記ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コンピュータBでSSHが有効なら （大抵はデフォルトの状態で有効だと思います）
コンピュータA側で、[PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) のplink.exeをアプリケーションから呼び出せば 実現出切ると思います。

plink は コマンドラインのSSHクライアントです。
使い方の例ですが、次の例は、`myhost` というLinuxホストに `myuser` ユーザで ログインして `python --version` コマンドを実行しています。

(例) C:>plink -pw mypass -batch myuser@myhost "python --version"
Python 2.6.6

オプションの `-pw mypass` は ログインパスワードを指定しています。
`-batch` は対話的なメッセージを抑止するオプションで、入力待ちで処理が進まない事を回避する意味があります。
この他のオプションは、plink を引数無しで実行すると使い方が表示されるのでご覧ください。

```
C:\>plink
Plink: command-line connection utility
Release 0.67
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
       ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw -serial
            force use of a particular protocol
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
  -sercfg configuration-string (e.g. 19200,8,n,1,X)
            Specify the serial configuration (serial only)
The following options only apply to SSH connections:
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -D [listen-IP:]listen-port
            Dynamic SOCKS-based port forwarding
  -L [listen-IP:]listen-port:host:port
            Forward local port to remote address
  -R [listen-IP:]listen-port:host:port
            Forward remote port to local address
  -X -x     enable / disable X11 forwarding
  -A -a     enable / disable agent forwarding
  -t -T     enable / disable pty allocation
  -1 -2     force use of particular protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for user authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -hostkey aa:bb:cc:...
            manually specify a host key (may be repeated)
  -m file   read remote command(s) from file
  -s        remote command is an SSH subsystem (SSH-2 only)
  -N        don't start a shell/command (SSH-2 only)
  -nc host:port
            open tunnel in place of session (SSH-2 only)
  -sshlog file
  -sshrawlog file
            log protocol details to a file
```

Answer (score -1):

Linux上のコマンドをリモートから実行するには`rsh`がよく使われていて、呼び出す側がWindows 10であれば"Bash on Windows"環境のrshコマンドでやりたい事が実現できると思います。

なお、今回の例であればprogram.pyが置いてある=命令を受け取る側の**コンピュータB**上で予めrshサーバを動作させておく必要があります。

参考：
[Bash on Ubuntu on Windowsとは？ そのインストールと使い方 - Build Insider](http://www.buildinsider.net/enterprise/bashonwindows/01)
[Windows10でrshコマンドを使いたい](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/f324a8c5-bc1b-4dbd-b283-5c06ebd5bd90/windows10rsh?forum=win10itprogeneralJP)